# Error while getting informations from json to Android

Tags: android, json

I want to get some informations from a database to my android app using JSON, but  whene I run my app I have an error in the LOG, exactly in this line : `JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_pays_detials, "GET", params);`

Here is my JAVA CODE :

**ViewPays.java**

```
package com.example.projet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewPays extends Activity {

TextView pays, langue, capitale, monnaie, richesse;
ImageView img;
static String  imageLocation="";
String return_img="", id;

//Progress bar
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single pays url
private static final String url_pays_detials = "http://goldengym.ma/myTest/get_pays.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCES = "succes";
private static final String TAG_PAYS = "pays";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NOM = "nom";
private static final String TAG_PHOTO = "photo";
private static final String TAG_LANGUE = "langage";
private static final String TAG_CAPITALE = "capitale";
private static final String TAG_MONNAIE = "monnaie";
private static final String TAG_RICHESSE = "richesse";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.pays);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_pays);

    // getting pays details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting pays id (pid) from intent
    id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

    // Getting complete pays details in background thread
    new GetPaysDetails().execute();
}

class GetPaysDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewPays.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Chargement des détails...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Check for success tag
            int succes;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                // getting pays details by making HTTP request
                // Note that pays details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_pays_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single pays Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                succes = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCES);
                if (succes == 1) {
                    // successfully received pays details
                    JSONArray paysObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PAYS); // JSON Array

                    // get first pays object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject r_pays = paysObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // pays with this pid found
                    // Edit Text
                    pays = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_pays);
                    langue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lang);
                    capitale = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_capitale);
                    monnaie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_monnaie);
                    richesse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_richesse);

                    // display pays data in EditText
                    pays.setText(r_pays.getString(TAG_NOM));
                    langue.setText(r_pays.getString(TAG_LANGUE));
                    capitale.setText(r_pays.getString(TAG_CAPITALE));
                    monnaie.setText(r_pays.getString(TAG_MONNAIE));
                    richesse.setText(r_pays.getString(TAG_RICHESSE));
                    return_img = r_pays.getString(TAG_PHOTO);
                    loadImage(return_img);

                    }else{
                        // pays with pid not found
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }       
}
Bitmap bitmap;
void loadImage(String image_location){
      URL imageURL = null;
      try {
          imageURL = new URL(image_location);
       }
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
      try {
       HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
       connection.setDoInput(true);
       connection.connect();
          InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//Convert to bitmap
          img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
}
```

And **JSONParser.java**

```
package com.example.projet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

**LOG**

```
03-05 22:45:00.978: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(20943):   --> package:com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:01.243: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(20943):   --> update package com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:01.243: D/Launcher.LauncherModel(20943):   --> package:com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:01.363: V/BackupManagerService(20666): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:01.518: D/PackageBroadcastService(21010): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:01.983: V/BackupManagerService(20666): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:03.133: W/DeepLinking(29845): no deep link install data found for com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:03.328: D/PackageBroadcastService(21010): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:03.338: D/PackageAddedReceiver(20848): package added com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:03.748: D/PackageBroadcastService(21010): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.projet
03-05 22:45:08.013: E/AndroidRuntime(30717):    at com.example.projet.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
03-05 22:45:08.013: E/AndroidRuntime(30717):    at com.example.projet.ViewPays$GetPaysDetails$1.run(ViewPays.java:99)
```

Can you please help me solving this error :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the log showing the error?

Comment: Sure I will add it to my post

Comment: No one can suggest a solution ? :)

Comment: The log you posted doesn't show the actual Exception thrown. But it does tell you exactly what line. Line 62 inside the makeHttpRequest method is where the problem is. Have you ran a debugger yet? Do you know what the exception is and why its usually thrown?